# SQL update row based on select

Tags: sql

I have a table in the following form

```
id username postcode assign .....
1  dave     123456   1      .....
2  steve    932495   2      .....
.. ..       ..       ..     .....
n  barry    92394    n      .....
```

I have a select query which picks out the relevant user ids

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE postcode LIKE "something"
```

What would be the best way of setting the `assign` column to some predetermined integer for all users picked out by my query?

Answer (score 2):

If you are updating a column in the same table this is a very basic UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE users SET assign = 5 WHERE postcode LIKE "something"
```

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
update users 
set assign = m
where postcode LIKE "something";
```

m will be the integer number you want to set to those records.

Thanks!,
@leo